# Is is potentially harmful to have a vitreous-enamel item in a small poorly-ventilated room?

Tags: materials

I am planning to purchase two enamel photo-frames for a room in the attic which is short in height and not well-ventilated. I would like to know if enamel like that is subject to deterioration that may leach fumes or such in the setting.

I have read a lot of pieces online about its composition often involving harmful chemicals like lead and cadmium, and I wish to know if there is any chance of potential adverse exposure in a finished enamel product.

EDIT: This potential percolation of such toxic chemicals on contact-surfaces is an [established fact](https://www.sgs.com/en/news/2018/12/safeguards-15918-iso-publishes-completely-new-standard-for-food-contact-enamels), and has seen food-security agencies revise standards several times. Of course, food-contact surfaces are an instance where the deterioration is rapidified for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 5):

True vitreous enamel has any toxic chemicals embedded in glass, locked in place as is used for [nuclear storage](https://mo-sci.com/vitrification-nuclear-waste-management/). Furthermore, there are few volatile compounds of heavy metals, but certainly *any* volatile compound would have been removed at the [temperatures used in vitrification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitreous_enamel), 1000°C and higher.

However, **don't eat the vitreous-enameled photo frame...** since enamel is glass, and the sharp slivers are likely to harm your alimentary and digestive systems!

Comment: So you’re saying there is definitely never any prospect of such seepage as I suggest, irrespective of treatment and composition of the enamel?